# Java: getter/setter methods

Tags: java, reflection

How are a bean's getter methods invoked and set in various frameworks? is it only through reflections?

Comment: @Nikita: I think the OP is thinking of ORMs.

Comment: Some frameworks use reflection. Some modify the class' bytecode. Did you have a specific framework in mind?

Comment: I was thinking of modifying collections to filter the values, for that I needed to write a generic method which would retrieve the value within an object through a getter method. However I was told using reflections would hit performance of the code, So I was wondering how it is done in other frameworks without affecting performance.

Comment: @Matt Do you have any experience in the subject? I'd love to hear myself how it can be done efficiently. By bytecode, did you mean serializing instance first?

Comment: @Nikita: I don't really have experience beyond using Hibernate and EclipseLink for work. As I understand it, [bytecode instrumentation](http://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/pohjalai/k05/okk/seminar/Aarniala-instrumenting.pdf) mean modifying the entity class' bytecode at runtime. It's typically faster than reflection. I wasn't able to find any conclusive documentation, but I _think_ this is also how Hibernate creates its entity proxies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, most frameworks use reflections for that, with assumed requirement that you must use a proper getter / setter naming convention (getXXX and setXXX, or isXXX and setXXX for boolean property).

Performance may be an issue, but unless you benchmark your application and find reflections to be a major bottleneck, I would advise against premature optimization, and use reflections as the simplest solution. With that said, you may want to look at this article on replacing reflections with code generation:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0610/